# Upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics iOS SDK objective-c, @import FirebaseCrashlytics not found

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am converting Fabric iOS SDK to Firebase Crashlytics iOS SDK
I follow below firebase google docs link https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios

I already Installed pod according to link

```
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

According to docs when I try to import `@import FirebaseCrashlytics` . I get an error like @import FirebaseCrashlytics module not found.

I did not understand below code in firebase google docs link

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols.
```

Let me correct if I am wrong anywhere

Comment: Make sure the Podfile includes `use_frameworks!`. Otherwise module imports are not available.

Comment: Ya. Already includes use_frameworks!
see below pod file data -------
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FirebaseCrashlytics' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FirebaseCrashlytics

pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

  target 'FirebaseCrashlyticsTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'FirebaseCrashlyticsUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

Comment: May need to do a build to prime the Xcode module cache

Comment: @AnkurPatel have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @George, I solved it. I just follow documents of FirebaseCrashlytics iOS SDK.
do not forget to add Run Script
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" ----------
make sure check mark for " Show environment variables in build log"
still are you facing problems, please message me.
send your demo proj or main proj link I will install. I suggest you, please give me your demo project link. Sorry for late reply. I already implemented in my 2 projects. Thanks

Comment: @George have you solved your problem?
If you find solution, please tell us, hence we can also get an idea. Thanks

Comment: @AnkurPatel Fixed the issue, followed the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the script using Mac terminal by using the below command for dSYM upload.

1). project/ios% pod install

2). cd ..

3). project% /path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/downloaded dSYMs